# Htaccess - Redirecting to core domain instead of same file

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

My domain requests are redirecting to the root of the domain instead of the given file type when attempting to redirect non www to www.

For example; I want website ---.com/dogs to go to www.---.com/dogs but instead it goes to www.---.com.

I'm using Laravel. What could be wrong?

My htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    #rewrite
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /root/sslcert/--.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/sslcert/--.key
    ServerName www.--.com
    #ServerAlias --.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/website-live/public"
    <Directory /var/www/website-live/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried removing the conditions i added for the redirect and no redirect occurs, so only with the two lines under #rewrite do these issues occur

Comment: To be honest it looks ok to me and when I tested it it works as what you have expected. Not sure why!

Comment: I noticed that your Virtual Host is specifying SSL, could it be the redirected http also changes to https by your another mod_rewrite script?